# import data into nested folders

Tags: javascript

I get an error that it cannot find Data/feed. I am not sure why that
is but before when I had posts just in the components folder and
imported it worked. But now that I put Posts in the Posts folder which
is inside of the components folder all of a sudden it does not work
when I import it. Everything was working until I put Posts in its own
folder so I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

My import into Posts.js:

```
import feed from '../Data/feed';
```

My import into App.js:

```
import Posts from './components/Posts/Posts';
```

Screenshots (click to enlarge):

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: '.../Data/feed'; did you mean '../Data/feed' ?

Comment: no.. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` = "Current Directory"

`..` = "Parent Directory"

`...` = nothing.  That's something you made up.

Based on the file structure in your screenshot, from within `Posts.js`;

`.` = `src/components/Posts`

`..` = `src/components`

`../..` = `src`

`../../Data` = `src/Data`

`../../Data/feed` = `src/Data/feed`

Comment: If im importing Posts.js into App.js is it simply then `import Posts from './components/Posts/Posts';`

Comment: The location of `App.js` is `src/App.js`.  So from within that file, `.` = `src`.  So `./components/Posts/Posts` = `src/components/Posts/Posts`.